# Increasing the tail of exponential function

Tags: exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

Suppose I generate a number of random number according to the exponential distribution and convert them into probability values in R.

```
prob <-  data.frame(round(rexp(2000 ,0.5) , digits = 4))
colnames(prob) <- "V"
prob$V <- prob$V / max(prob$V)
hist(prob$V , prob= TRUE, breaks =30, main=" ", xlab= "Probability Vals", col="red")
lines(density(prob$V, adjust=2), lty="dotted", col="darkblue", lwd=2)
```

When I plot the distribution of the probability values, here how it looks;

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzWvm.png)

I would like to obtain something like

[second figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3rwQ.png)

I have found something called exponentially modified Gaussian distribution and select the parameters as $\mu= -3, \sigma =1, \lambda =0.25$ as shown at [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentially_modified_Gaussian_distribution). However, I am not getting the desired output. The R code is

```
prob <-  data.frame(round(rexp(2000 ,0.25)+ dnorm(2000, mean = -3, sd = 1, log = FALSE)   , digits = 4))
```

I was wondering if someone help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by "increase the height of the skewness uniformly"?  You can't just raise up the whole tail by a fixed amount, like in your figure.  The area under the curve must be 1.

Comment: "You can't just raise up the whole tail by a fixed amount, like in your figure." I know. That is why I am asking how should I generate the random numbers to obtain the desired distribution. or how should I go and update the random numbers generated. Since it does sound confusing, I removed that part from the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather you want an exponential-like distribution with a constant tail for $x$ which is zero away from the interval $0<x<1$. Such a PDF can be written

$$ P(x) = A \ \text{max}\big[C,e^{-\lambda x}\big]\big[\theta(x)-\theta(x-1)\big]$$

where $C<1$ and $0< 1/\lambda < 1$. $C$ is your constant tail, and the turnover from exponential-like to constant happens at $x = -\lambda^{-1}\log C$ (a positive number between 0 and 1). The normalization constant $A$ is determined by

$$1 = \int_0^1 P(x) dx = A \Big[ \int_0^{-\lambda^{-1}\log C}  e^{-\lambda x} dx  + \int_{-\lambda^{-1}\log C}^{1} C dx\Big],$$
and this gives
$$ A = -\frac{\lambda}{C(1+\log C)}$$
so

$$ P(x) = -\frac{\lambda}{C(1+\log C)} \ \text{max}\big[C,e^{-\lambda x}\big]\big[\theta(x)-\theta(x-1)\big].$$

If you want to draw random variables from this distribution, probably the best way is to sample from an exponential distribution and throw away values that don't work (A [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method)).

Comment: Does $\theta$ represent the exponential distribution? I will give it a try, thanks for the help.

Comment: $\theta$ is a heaviside step function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function. It's just enforcing the distribution zero everywhere except $0<x<1$.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what distribution you choose it will go to zero as $x$ goes to $\infty$. You could potentially ask that it goes to zero much slower than an exponential distribution, and there are many ways to achieve this. For instance you could choose the cdf to be $1-1/f$, where $f$ is a very slow growing function like $\log x$ or $\log \log x$. (To do this you might have to shift also to make it zero at $x=0$).

Putting this all together for $f = \log \log x$, say, a pdf with qualitatively very large tail is
$$
\frac{1}{(x+e^e)\log (x+e^e) \log^2\log (x+e^e)}
$$

Comment: Yes, but x does not go to infinity. If I need 1000 points which are between 0 and 1 and the distribution should look like as I shared in my post, how do I that? I tried the log transformation as you suggested, but did not work.

Comment: If you want just uniformly chosen values up to a certain max value, use a uniform distribution. This answer contemplates that you want it to be possible for the distribution to choose arbitrarily large values.

Comment: If I use uniform distribution, I would not get an exponential like distribution tho. All I want is to have numbers between 0 and 1. I also want those numbers exponentially distributed while the right tail is high. For example, I found log-normal distribution at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution. If you look at the blue image, I want my numbers distributed like that.

Comment: It sounds like you know the distribution you want. Whats wrong with choosing the one you want?

Comment: When I generate random number according to log-normal and normalize it, I am getting exactly the same result. The right tail is super flat and close to zero. The code is ```prob <-  data.frame(round(rlnorm(2000, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1) , digits = 4))```

Comment: Sounds like you need to tweak the parameters of the distribution until it looks the way you want it to. For instance increasing sdlog will make the distribution more spread out.